# Multi-Type ElasticSearch search request NEST C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to implement Elasticsearch in my Public Transport algorithm to get GTFS data but don't know what is the "best" way to get the data that I need (Note : I'm using NEST in C# ).

I have indexed 2 classes :

```
public class StopTimes : IGTFS
{
     public string trip_id;
     public string arrival_time;
     public string departure_time;
     public string stop_id;
     public string stop_sequence;
     public string stop_headsign;
     public string shape_dist_traveled; 
}

public class Trips : IGTFS
{
    public string route_id;
    public string service_id;
    public string trip_id;
    public string trip_head_sign;
    public string trip_short_name;
    public string direction_id;
    public string shape_id;
}
```

I am wondering how I can, from a `stop_id`, get all the corresponding `route_id` in a simple request (a stop can belong to several routes).

Currently, I'm trying to do it in 2 steps knowing that a `stop_id` can be matched in several `StopTimes` and  several `trip_id`s belong to a single `route_id` (I have 6k `trip_id`s for 8 `route_id`s).

- I'm getting all the `StopTimes` (more than 2k hits) data where the `stop_id` match.

  ```
          var result = _client.Search(s => s
          .Index("gtfs_data")
          .Type("stoptimes")
          .Fields("trip_id")
          .Query(q => q
              .Term("stop_id", id)).Size(10000000)
          );
  ```
- Then I try to get the `route_id` in Trips but I don't really know how to proceed ( facets? )

  ```
      var result2 = _client.Search<Trips>(s => s
                 .Index(_ratpData)
                 .Query(q => q
                 .Terms(t => t.trip_id, terms)) //terms = array of stop_id
                 .FacetTerm(t=>t
                      .OnField(f=>f.route_id).Size(10000000))
                 );
  ```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is the way your data is indexed, sounds like your first query also need to be a facet - You want all the trip_ids for a stop_id so you want a facet on the trip_id (and not bringing back all the actual stoptimes).
And then the next query is a facet on the route_id like you specified. 
Make sure to set your search type to count to improve performance (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/).

Another option, if a trip_id always belongs to a single route_id, is to use parent - child relationship between Trips and StopTimes. You set the Trip as the parent of the StopTime in the mapping (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field/), you index each stoptime with the trip as its parent, and then you can use the has_child query or filter (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-query/) to bring all the Trips (route_ids) for a certain stop_id.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't think about parent, I'll try that way :)